# You are submitting requests too quickly. Please retry your requests at a slower rate. Amazon API

Tags: php, error, api, amazon-web-services

Hi this is the error Im getting when calling the api from amazon on my magento products , I get few responses back and then this error at the bottom :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [aws:Client.RequestThrottled] AWS Access Key ID: *****************. You are submitting requests too quickly. Please retry your requests at a slower rate. in /var/www/html/AmazonApi.php:93 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/AmazonApi.php(93): SoapClient->__soapCall('ItemLookup', Array) #1 /var/www/html/apicall/itemSearch.php(35): AmazonAPI->sendRequest(Array) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/AmazonApi.php on line 93
```

**The question is how to slow down number of requests ?**

This is my amazon api :

AmazonApi.php

```
class AmazonAPI{
private static $instance;

private $public_key;
private $secret_key;
private $associate_tag;//This is only for Amazon affiliates

private $wsdl_url='http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl';
private $webservices_url='https://webservices.amazon.com/onca/soap?Service=AWSECommerceService';

public function __construct($publicKey, $secretKey, $associateTag){
    if(!empty($publicKey)){
        $this->public_key = $publicKey;
    }

    if(!empty($secretKey)){
        $this->secret_key = $secretKey;
    }

    if(!empty($associateTag)){
        $this->associate_tag = $associateTag;
    }
    }

    //Send a request to amazon
    public function sendRequest($request_params){
    $params['Request']=$request_params;
    $operation=$request_params['Operation'];

    if(isset($this->associate_tag)){
        $params['AssociateTag']=$this->associate_tag;
    }

    $soapy=new SoapClient(
        $this->wsdl_url,
        array('exceptions'=>1)
    );

    $soapy->__setLocation($this->webservices_url);

    $current_timestamp=gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
    $req_sig=$this->createSignature($operation,$current_timestamp);

    $headers_array=array(
        new SoapHeader(
            'http://security.amazonaws.com/doc/2007-01-01/',
            'AWSAccessKeyId',
            $this->public_key
        ),
        new SoapHeader(
            'http://security.amazonaws.com/doc/2007-01-01/',
            'Timestamp',
            $current_timestamp
        ),
        new SoapHeader(
            'http://security.amazonaws.com/doc/2007-01-01/',
            'Signature',
            $req_sig
        )
    );
    $soapy->__setSoapHeaders($headers_array);

    return $soapy->__soapCall($operation,array($params));
    }


//Create signature for request
protected function createSignature($operation,$timestamp){
    $the_string=$operation.$timestamp;
    return base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256",$the_string,$this->secret_key,true));
}
}
```

itemLookup.php

```
  <?php
   require('../AmazonApi.php');

  //Create API access object
  $public_key = 'PUBLIC-KEY';
  $secret_key = 'SECRET-KEY';
  $associate_tag = 'TAG';
  $amazon_api = new AmazonAPI($public_key, $secret_key, $associate_tag);



         $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addStoreFilter(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID) // default store
->addAttributeToSelect('sku');

   //  foreach($collection as $product)
{
  // $product->getSku();
 //$asin = substr($sku,0,10);
 }

 //Array of request parameters
 foreach($collection as $product)
 {
 $params_array = array(
'Operation' => 'ItemLookup',
'IdType' => 'ASIN',
'ItemId' => $asin = substr($sku,0,10) ,
'ResponseGroup' => 'Tracks'
 );

// returns a list of items for the search query 'Slow Magic'
$response = $amazon_api->sendRequest($params_array);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
echo '</pre>';
}
foreach($parsed_xml->OperationRequest->Errors->Error as $error){
echo "Error code: " . $error->Code . "\r\n";
echo $error->Message . "\r\n";
echo "\r\n";
}
```

Thank you for any useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the answer for this.

Amazon API only allows 10 requests per second, the idea is to slow it down.
This is the code you can use:

```
*$response = $amazon_api->sendRequest($params_array);*
foreach ($response as $restponse)
{
 sleep(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good resource.
http://www.manualslib.com/manual/530017/Amazon-Product-Advertising-Api.html?page=160

*" If this is the case, you need to slow your request rate to one request per second."

If you abuse it Amazon will throttle you greatly.
How your API calls are getting generated can vary on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same problem even if I put 1 or more seconds delay.

I believe when you begin to make too much requests with only one second delay, Amazon doesn't like that and thinks you're a spammer.

You'll have to generate another key pair (and use it when making further requests) and put a delay of 1.1 second to be able to make fast requests again.

This worked for me.